# Images missing in infinite ajax scroll in IE (unless dev tools or zoom in use)

Tags: internet-explorer, infinite-scroll

I'm using ajax infinite scrolling on magento product list pages. It works fine in Chrome, Firefox and Safari but in Internet Explorer when it gets to the next page these next set of images are missing and only the image name appears (the images earlier in the page are present). I've flushed the caches, ensured the images are where the path leads to, checked media permissions, increased php memory limit, reindexed.

When I turn on developer tools or change the zoom the images appear again like magic. When a new page is reached the next set of images are just the names. Why would it work only if I zoom or press F12 dev tools? There are no errors on the console or in the logs.

Page 1 is always fine, it's just the next pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it transpired that IE did not like the following within the `list.phtml` file.

```
srcset="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product,'small_image')->constrainOnly(TRUE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize($_imgSize); ?> 1x,

<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product,'small_image')->constrainOnly(TRUE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize(2*$_imgSize); ?> 2x"
```

I reverted to using src.

```
src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize($_imgSize); ?>"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are likley using picturefill or respimage polyfill for not supporting browsers.

Simply write `picturefill` or `respimage` into your dev console.

In case new elements are added to the dom, you need to call the polyfill function. (Either `picturefill();` or `respimage();`).

Check your infinite scroll plugin, there should be an event, that is fired as soon as new elements are added.

In case you use respimage or picturefill 3.0-beta, you can also add the [mutation plugin](https://github.com/scottjehl/picturefill/tree/3.0/dist/plugins/mutation).

Another workaround is to use [lazySizes](https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes), because lazysizes also automatically detects new image elements.